# Group by using base R

Tags: r

## Dataset

I have a datasets with column year,quarter,Channel,sales,units

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L
), quarter = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Q1", 
"Q2", "Q3", "Q4"), class = "factor"), Channel = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), class = "factor"), 
    sales = c(2023L, 2231L, 2832L, 1905L, 2057L, 2099L, 2558L, 
    2302L, 2505L, 2128L, 2163L, 1128L, 1436L, 2169L, 2476L, 1533L, 
    2114L, 2613L, 1614L, 2884L, 2335L, 1990L, 2187L, 2695L), 
    units = c(12L, 12L, 18L, 24L, 23L, 11L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 13L, 
    11L, 25L, 14L, 23L, 19L, 11L, 23L, 21L, 15L, 15L, 11L, 17L, 
    13L, 14L)), .Names = c("year", "quarter", "Channel", "sales", 
"units"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"))
```

How can I do sum of sales and mean of units group by  year,quarter,Channel without using any package. (With base R)

The output should be:

```
year quarter Channel sales units
 1: 2013      Q1     AAA  4855  15.0
 2: 2013      Q1     BBB  2231  12.0
 3: 2013      Q2     AAA  4004  17.5
 4: 2013      Q2     BBB  2057  23.0
 5: 2013      Q3     AAA  2558  21.0
 6: 2013      Q3     BBB  4807  21.0
 7: 2013      Q4     AAA  4291  12.0
 8: 2013      Q4     BBB  1128  25.0
 9: 2014      Q1     CCC  3912  16.5
10: 2014      Q1     AAA  2169  23.0
11: 2014      Q2     BBB  1533  11.0
12: 2014      Q2     CCC  2114  23.0
13: 2014      Q2     AAA  2613  21.0
14: 2014      Q3     CCC  1614  15.0
15: 2014      Q3     BBB  5219  13.0
16: 2014      Q4     BBB  4177  15.0
17: 2014      Q4     AAA  2695  14.0
```

Comment: Look at `?aggregate` from base R.

Comment: please tell how to use aggregate on two or more measures and two or more dimensions

Comment: This output looks like it was taken from `data.table`. I thought Base R only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another base R solution using `by`

```
do.call(rbind, by(df, df[, 1:3], 
                  function(x) cbind(x[1, 1:3], sum(x$sales), mean(x$units))))
```

Or using "*split\apply\combine*" theory

```
t(sapply(split(df, df[, 1:3], drop = TRUE), 
                   function(x) c(sumSales = sum(x$sales), meanUnits = mean(x$units))))
```

Or similarly

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df[, 1:3], drop = TRUE), 
                     function(x) c(sumSales = sum(x$sales), meanUnits = mean(x$units))))
```

---

**Edit:** it seems like `df` is of class `data.table` (but you for some reason asked for base R solution only), here's how you would do it with your `data.table` object

```
df[, .(sumSales = sum(sales), meanUnits = mean(units)), keyby = .(year, quarter, Channel)]
#     year quarter Channel sumSales meanUnits
#  1: 2013      Q1     AAA     4855      15.0
#  2: 2013      Q1     BBB     2231      12.0
#  3: 2013      Q2     AAA     4004      17.5
#  4: 2013      Q2     BBB     2057      23.0
#  5: 2013      Q3     AAA     2558      21.0
#  6: 2013      Q3     BBB     4807      21.0
#  7: 2013      Q4     AAA     4291      12.0
#  8: 2013      Q4     BBB     1128      25.0
#  9: 2014      Q1     AAA     2169      23.0
# 10: 2014      Q1     CCC     3912      16.5
# 11: 2014      Q2     AAA     2613      21.0
# 12: 2014      Q2     BBB     1533      11.0
# 13: 2014      Q2     CCC     2114      23.0
# 14: 2014      Q3     BBB     5219      13.0
# 15: 2014      Q3     CCC     1614      15.0
# 16: 2014      Q4     AAA     2695      14.0
# 17: 2014      Q4     BBB     4177      15.0
```

Comment: The output should be:

Comment: The output should be:                                                                                                         year quarter Channel sales units
 1: 2013      Q1     AAA  4855  15.0
 2: 2013      Q1     BBB  2231  12.0
 3: 2013      Q2     AAA  4004  17.5
 4: 2013      Q2     BBB  2057  23.0
 5: 2013      Q3     AAA  2558  21.0
 6: 2013      Q3     BBB  4807  21.0
 7: 2013      Q4     AAA  4291  12.0
 8: 2013      Q4     BBB  1128  25.0
 9: 2014      Q1     CCC  3912  16.5
10: 2014      Q1     AAA  2169  23.0
11: 2014      Q2     BBB  1533  11.0
so on ....

Comment: Did you try my code? This is exactly the output you are getting. If you don't like the row names you can do `row.names(res) <- NULL` (if `res` is where saved the results)

Comment: your output is : sumSales meanUnits
1    15187    15.875
2    18107    17.625
3    18683    17.500

Comment: I think you have a `data.table` object. Didn't you say base R only? In order my code to work on you object use `df <- as.data.frame(df)` before running the code. Or do `setDF(df)` and then run it. But I'm confused, why do you have a `data.table` object and you want base R solution. It is easily solved with `data.table`

Comment: I dont want to use data.table as I need to install this package. Can we somehow use aggregate function.????

Comment: I told you. Do `df <- as.data.frame(df)` and then run my code.

Comment: df[, .(sumSales = sum(sales), meanUnits = mean(units)), keyby = .(year, quarter, Channel)]. Its awesome code. Could you explain me what is the meaning of .(dot) here and keyby. Thanks

Comment: Is it working for you? It means that you have `data.table` installed already. This is `data.table` syntax. `keyby = .()` is just where you put your aggregation variables. `keyby` means that you want to sort by these variables. You can use `by` instead of `keyby` if you don't want to sort.

Comment: Yeah thats in my PC but in client server i cant install data.table thats the problem.

Comment: On the client PC my original code will work. It didn't work on your computer because you had `data.table` object. But your client will have a normal `data.frame`.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
aggregate(sales~year+quarter+Channel, data=df, FUN = sum) # sum of sale
aggregate(units~year+quarter+Channel, data=df, FUN = mean) # mean of units
```

Comment: You can calculate both at the same line, something like `function(x) c(sum(x), mean(x))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, the variables are different (Sales and Units).

Comment: @docendodiscimus Oh  right, then it's a good use case for `data.table` and `dplyr`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I agree, but OP is looking for a way using only base R

Comment: @docendodiscimus Didn't read it.. Added a one liner using `by` and `split` then.